# Measure capacitance with Arduino and AD7746

Tags: arduino, measurement, capacitance, converter, code

I want to measure capacitance with an Arduino and an [AD7746](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7745_7746.pdf) capacitive sensor.

I already used ChatGPT and some examples, but the sensor measures just 0 pF. When I measure with an LCR meter, the initial C was about 10 pF.

This is figure with the pin locations:

[image]

This is the code that I used:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include "AD7746.h"

// Initialize AD7746 object
AD7746 ad7746;

void setup() {
  // Initialize I2C communication
  Wire.begin();
  
  // Initialize serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  // Initialize AD7746
  ad7746.initialize();
  
  // Check connection
  if (ad7746.testConnection()) {
    Serial.println("AD7746 connection successful");
  } else {
    Serial.println("AD7746 connection failed");
    while (1); // Loop forever if connection fails
  }
}

void loop() {
  // Get capacitance measurement
  uint32_t capacitance = ad7746.getCapacitance();
  
  // Convert capacitance to farads (F) using calibration coefficient
  float farads = capacitance * AD7746_DAC_COEFFICIENT;
  
  // Print capacitance measurement in farads
  Serial.print("Capacitance: ");
  Serial.print(farads, 8); // Print with 8 decimal places for precision
  Serial.println(" F");
  
  delay(1000); // Delay for 1 second
}
```

This is the header code:

```cpp
#ifndef _AD7746_H_
#define _AD7746_H_

#include "I2Cdev.h"

#define AD7746_ADDRESS           0x48
#define AD7746_DEFAULT_ADDRESS   AD7746_ADDRESS           

#define AD7746_RA_STATUS                 0x00 // Status
#define AD7746_RA_CAP_DATA_H             0x01 // Cap data
#define AD7746_RA_CAP_DATA_M             0x02 // Cap data
#define AD7746_RA_CAP_DATA_L             0x03 // Cap data
#define AD7746_RA_VT_DATA_H              0x04 // VT data
#define AD7746_RA_VT_DATA_M              0x05 // VT data
#define AD7746_RA_VT_DATA_L              0x06 // VT data
#define AD7746_RA_CAP_SETUP              0x07 // Cap Setup
#define AD7746_RA_VT_SETUP               0x08 // VT Setup
#define AD7746_RA_EXC_SETUP              0x09 // Exc Setup
#define AD7746_RA_CONFIGURATION          0x0A // Configuration
#define AD7746_RA_CAP_DAC_A              0x0B // Cap DAC A
#define AD7746_RA_CAP_DAC_B              0x0C // Cap DAC B
#define AD7746_RA_CAP_OFF_H              0x0D 
#define AD7746_RA_CAP_OFF_L              0x0E 
#define AD7746_RA_CAP_GAIN_H             0x0F
#define AD7746_RA_CAP_GAIN_L             0x10
#define AD7746_RA_VOLT_GAIN_H            0x11
#define AD7746_RA_VOLT_GAIN_L            0x12

#define AD7746_RESET                     0xBF

// Status
#define AD7746_EXCERR_BIT                3
#define AD7746_RDY_BIT                   2
#define AD7746_RDYVT_BIT                 1
#define AD7746_RDYCAP_BIT                0

// Cap Setup
#define AD7746_CAPEN_BIT                 7
#define AD7746_CIN2_BIT                  6
#define AD7746_CAPDIFF_BIT               5
#define AD7746_CACHOP_BIT                0

#define AD7746_CAPEN                     (1 << AD7746_CAPEN_BIT)
#define AD7746_CIN2                      (1 << AD7746_CIN2_BIT)

// VT Setup
#define AD7746_VTEN_BIT                  7
#define AD7746_VTMD_BIT_1                6
#define AD7746_VTMD_BIT_0                5
#define AD7746_EXTREF_BIT                4
#define AD7746_VTSHORT_BIT               1
#define AD7746_VTCHOP_BIT                0

#define AD7746_VTEN                      (1 << AD7746_VTEN_BIT)

#define AD7746_VTMD_INT_TEMP             0
#define AD7746_VTMD_EXT_TEMP             (1 << AD7746_VTMD_BIT_0)
#define AD7746_VTMD_VDD_MON              (1 << AD7746_VTMD_BIT_1)
#define AD7746_VTMD_VIN                  (1 << AD7746_VTMD_BIT_1) | (1 << AD7746_VTMD_BIT_0)

// Exc Setup
#define AD7746_CLKCTRL_BIT               7 
#define AD7746_EXCON_BIT                 6                                            
#define AD7746_EXCB_BIT                  5
#define AD7746_INV_EXCB_BIT              4
#define AD7746_EXCA_BIT                  3
#define AD7746_INV_EXCA_BIT              2
#define AD7746_EXCLVL_BIT_1              1
#define AD7746_EXCLVL_BIT_0              0

#define AD7746_EXCA                      (1 << AD7746_EXCA_BIT)
#define AD7746_EXCB                      (1 << AD7746_EXCB_BIT)
#define AD7746_EXCON                     (1 << AD7746_EXCON_BIT)

#define AD7746_EXCLVL_VDD_X_1_8          0
#define AD7746_EXCLVL_VDD_X_1_4          (1 << AD7746_EXCLVL_BIT_0)
#define AD7746_EXCLVL_VDD_X_3_8          (1 << AD7746_EXCLVL_BIT_1)
#define AD7746_EXCLVL_VDD_X_1_2          (1 << AD7746_EXCLVL_BIT_1) | (1 << AD7746_EXCLVL_BIT_0)

// Configuration
#define AD7746_VTF_BIT_1                 7
#define AD7746_VTF_BIT_0                 6
#define AD7746_CAPF_BIT_2                5
#define AD7746_CAPF_BIT_1                4
#define AD7746_CAPF_BIT_0                3
#define AD7746_MD_BIT_2                  2
#define AD7746_MD_BIT_1                  1
#define AD7746_MD_BIT_0                  0

#define AD7746_VTF_20P1                  0
#define AD7746_VTF_32P1                  (1 << AD7746_VTF_BIT_0)
#define AD7746_VTF_62P1                  (1 << AD7746_VTF_BIT_1)
#define AD7746_VTF_122P1                 (1 << AD7746_VTF_BIT_1) | (1 << AD7746_VTF_BIT_0)

#define AD7746_CAPF_11P0                 0
#define AD7746_CAPF_11P9                 (1 << AD7746_CAPF_BIT_0)
#define AD7746_CAPF_20P0                 (1 << AD7746_CAPF_BIT_1)
#define AD7746_CAPF_38P0                 (1 << AD7746_CAPF_BIT_1) | (1 << AD7746_CAPF_BIT_0)
#define AD7746_CAPF_62P0                 (1 << AD7746_CAPF_BIT_2)
#define AD7746_CAPF_77P0                 (1 << AD7746_CAPF_BIT_2) | (1 << AD7746_CAPF_BIT_0)
#define AD7746_CAPF_92P0                 (1 << AD7746_CAPF_BIT_2) | (1 << AD7746_CAPF_BIT_1)
#define AD7746_CAPF_109P6                (1 << AD7746_CAPF_BIT_2) | (1 << AD7746_CAPF_BIT_1) | (1 << AD7746_CAPF_BIT_0)

#define AD7746_MD_IDLE                   0
#define AD7746_MD_CONTINUOUS_CONVERSION  (1 << AD7746_MD_BIT_0)
#define AD7746_MD_SINGLE_CONVERSION      (1 << AD7746_MD_BIT_1)
#define AD7746_MD_POWER_DOWN             (1 << AD7746_MD_BIT_1) | (1 << AD7746_MDF_BIT_0)
#define AD7746_MD_OFFSET_CALIBRATION     (1 << AD7746_MD_BIT_2) | (1 << AD7746_MD_BIT_0)
#define AD7746_MD_GAIN_CALIBRATION       (1 << AD7746_MD_BIT_2) | (1 << AD7746_MD_BIT_1)

// Cap DAC A
#define AD7746_DACAEN_BIT                7

#define AD7746_DACAEN                    (1 << AD7746_DACAEN_BIT)

// Cap DAC B
#define AD7746_DACBEN_BIT                7

#define AD7746_DACBEN                    (1 << AD7746_DACBEN_BIT)

#define AD7746_DAC_COEFFICIENT           0.13385826771654F // 17pF/127

class AD7746 {
    public:
        AD7746();
        AD7746(uint8_t address);

        void initialize();
        bool testConnection();
        void reset(); 

        uint32_t getCapacitance();
    
        void writeCapSetupRegister(uint8_t data);
        void writeVtSetupRegister(uint8_t data);
        void writeExcSetupRegister(uint8_t data);
        void writeConfigurationRegister(uint8_t data);
        void writeCapDacARegister(uint8_t data);
        void writeCapDacBRegister(uint8_t data);
        void write_register(uint8_t addr,uint8_t data);
        

    private:
        uint8_t devAddr;
        uint8_t buffer[19];
};

#endif /* _AD7746_H_ */
```

Are there any errors in the code? When I use this code, I only get 0 pF. I already checked the I2C communication, but there is no problem there.

How can I measure using my sensor?

Comment: Add some debugging code to see what's going on. For instance,  you're printing `farads` with 8 decimals but it will always be an integer, since you multiply an integer by a float. You would discover that if you printed the raw `capacitance` value as well.

Comment: I would start by looking at the data sheet.  There is probably some additional setup that the chip requires in order to properly read the capacitance.

Comment: I check the i2c communication is fine.  Here is the datasheet of AD7746. I hope to solve this problem...  Thank you
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7745_7746.pdf